# How to check COLUMN_FORMAT IN Mysql

Tags: mysql

I Used MySQL 8.0

```
CREATE TABLE `Column_Format` (
`COL`  VARCHAR(25) NULL 
     COLUMN_FORMAT DEFAULT,
`COL2` VARCHAR(25) NULL, 
`COL3` VARCHAR(25) NULL  );

CREATE TABLE `Column_Format2` (
`COL`  VARCHAR(25) NULL  
     COLUMN_FORMAT DYNAMIC,
`COL2` VARCHAR(25) NULL, 
`COL3` VARCHAR(25) NULL );

CREATE TABLE `Column_Format3` (
`COL`  VARCHAR(25) NULL 
     COLUMN_FORMAT FIXED,
`COL2` VARCHAR(25) NULL, 
`COL3` VARCHAR(25) NULL  );
```

The column types supported by MySQL are DEFAULT, FIXED, and DYNAMIC.

And I want to know what the type of each column is, but unfortunately
In Inforamtion.columns, it is not possible to inquire what the column format of a column is.

How can I query it?

Comment: are you using NDB?  if you aren't, I believe COLUMN_FORMAT is just ignored

Comment: even not using NDB, it shows up in `show create table yourtablename`, so it is stored somewhere, but doesn't seem to be anywhere accessible through information_schema

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the `COLUMN_FORMAT` since it is most likely ignored by MySQL when you run your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

As documented in [the official CREATE TABLE documentation for MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html):

> COLUMN_FORMAT currently has no effect on columns of tables using storage engines other than NDB. MySQL 8.0 silently ignores COLUMN_FORMAT.

More information about [MySQL NBD cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-cluster.html)

Non-ignored options are normally available with:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'some_test_table'\G
```